# Showing two diffrenent pages in a mainwindow in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am new to PyQt5 and trying to design a calculator that could switch between two modes through a push button in PyQt5. I've set a new widget in grid layout in the main window to store the two different widgets and shows them when needed. However, the `self.window1.show()` does not show out the window1 widget. How can I deal with this? Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
    def AddWidgets(self):
        self.main_widget = QWidget() 
        self.main_widget.setObjectName('main_widget')
        self.main_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.window1 = Digcalculator()
        self.window2 = CalculusCalculator()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.window1, 1, 1, 10, 10)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.window2, 1, 1, 10, 10)

    def action(self):
        self.window1.show()
        self.Button2Simple.clicked.connect(self.changeMode)  # if the change button is clicked
```

Comment: Have a look at QStackedWidget.

Comment: @0010SS You're just showing `window1`, but that is a child of `main_widget`, which doesn't seem to be called anywhere. If you don't provide us a [mre] we cannot help you more on that. Besides, if you want to switch between widgets, you must use QStackedWidget as suggested by Passerby.

Comment: Thanks! I will check QStackedWidget out.